# C++ Directory Watching - How to detect copy has ended

Tags: c++, windows, visual-c++, directory

I have a folder to which files are copied. I want to watch it and process files as soon as they are copied to the directory. I can detect when a file is in the directory, whether through polling (my current implementation) or in some tests using Windows APIs from a few samples I've found online.

The problem is that I detect when the file is first created and its still being copied. This makes my program, that needs to access the file, through errors (because the file is not yet complete). How can I detect not when the copying started but when the copying ended? I'm using C++ on Windows, so the answer may be platform dependent but, if possible, I'd prefer it to be platform agnostic.

Comment: I found this question just a few minutes ago: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/559659/how-to-know-a-file-is-finished-copying It's very similar to my problem but the "approved" solution is far from being elegant and functional.

Comment: If your code will be running in an administrative context, i.e., as a system service, you could use a change journal.  See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa363798%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

Comment: Considering the possibility of things like naive copying using `fread()`/`fwrite()` i don't think there is a general solution. Not quite robust, but maybe by tracking open handles to the files?

Answer (score 4):

You could use either lock files or a special naming convention. The easiest is the latter and would work something like this:

Say you want to move a file named "fileA.txt" When copying it to the destination directory, instead, copy it to "fileA.txt.partial" or something like that. When the copy is complete, rename the file from "fileA.txt.partial" to "fileA.txt". So the appearance of "fileA.txt" is atomic as far as the watching program can see.

The other option as mentioned earlier is lock files. So when you copy a file named "fileA.txt", you first create a file called "fileA.txt.lock". When the copying is done, you simply delete the lock file. When the watching program see "fileA.txt", it should check if "fileA.txt.lock" exists, if it does, it can wait or revisit that file in the future as needed.

Comment: Well that's a workaround and might work on other environments. But on this case, I'm talking about files being copied by other programs/via the file explorer to a folder being watched by my program. In that case this approach is very hard to accomplish.

Comment: Not sure it's possible if you have no control over how the files are copied.

Answer (score 2):

You should not be polling. Use FindFirstChangeNotification (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa364417%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) to watch a directory for changes.

Then use the Wait functions (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms687069%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) to wait on change notifications to happen.

Overview and examples here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365261%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

I'm not sure how exactly file write completion can be determined. Evan Teran's answer is a good idea.

Comment: It's exactly because polling is not a good idea that I'm trying to replace it with something better ;)

And yeah! I found those methods and I already have a solution based on this: http://code.google.com/p/simplefilewatcher/. The problem is to determine file write completion. That library (that I have already modified slightly) uses ReadDirectoryChangesW that I believe it's even more powerful than FindFirstChangeNotification.

Comment: On a side note, I just wonder how Dropbox (for example) deals with this kind of issues.

Comment: You could try to open the file for exclusive write, which will fail until the copy is finished. There's probably a way to block on that condition, instead of polling it, but I don't know it offhand.

Comment: Yeap. I ended up doing something like that, with a long polling time (like 3 or 5 seconds). It's far from perfect but the Windows API doesn't allow something better.

Answer (score 0):

You can use something like this, This is tested and working

```
bool IsFileDownloadComplete(const std::wstring& dir, const std::wstring& fileName) 
{
    std::wstring originalFileName = dir + fileName;
    std::wstring tempFileName = dir + L"temp";

    while(true)
    {
        int ret = rename(convertWstringToString(originalFileName).c_str(), convertWstringToString(tempFileName).c_str());
        if(ret == 0)
            break;      

        Sleep(10);
    }   

    /** File is not open. Rename to original. */
    int ret = rename(convertWstringToString(tempFileName).c_str(), convertWstringToString(originalFileName).c_str());
    if(ret != 0)
        throw std::exception("File rename failed"); 

    return true;
}
```